# Django join with sum

Tags: django, database, orm

I have two models, Transaction and TransactionType.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    tran_date = models.DateField()
    tran_amount = models.FloatField(default=0.00)
    tran_payment_method = models.ForeignKey(PaymentMethod,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    tran_location = models.ForeignKey(Location,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    tran_type = models.ForeignKey(TransactionType,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

class TransactionType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)  # 0:inactive 1:active
    income_ind=models.IntegerField(default=0) # 1: expense 2: income
    account = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

I want to use ORM to run a query like below

```
select b.name,sum(a.tran_amount) as total
from Transaction a
inner join TransactionType b
on a.tran_type = b.id
where a.account=some_user_id and b.income_ind=1
```

How should I implement this without using raw query?

Comment: I assume you forgot the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Furthermore: is the `TransactionType.name` unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `TransactionType.name` is unique (so there are no two `TransactionType`s with the *same* name), then we can use a `.annotate(..)` for that:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

TransactionType.objects.filter(
    transaction__acount_id=some_user_id
    income_ind=1
).annotate(
    total=Sum('transaction__tran_amount')
)
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` that contains `TransactionType`s, and every `TransactionType` will have an attribute `total` that is the sum of the `tran_amount`s for related `Transaction`s for which the `acount_id` is `some_user_id` (to be filled in).

We furthermore only consider `TransactionType`s for which `income_ind` is `1`.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I am new to Django queryset and get confused when query becomes complex, thanks for the help!